# how to write datatable in excel using power automate desktop while preventing large numbers to be converted to an exponent

Tags: excel, power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I am having an issue when writing a datatable to power automate desktop, the issue occurs when a cell has a large number, since it converts the data to exponent. Below is how I am writing the datatable to excel.

[image]

The datatable as it appears on PAD before pasting it in excel.

[image]

This is how the data appears in excel

[image]

How do I prevent PAD from reformatting the data before pasting as now its distorting a reference which is creating an issue in referencing.

Comment: Looks like it's a parsing issue rather than a formatting issue. Try wrapping the value to be written to Excel in [`TOSTRING()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/minit/string-operations#tostringintformat).

Comment: That doesn't work converting a datatable to string inserts the whole datatable in one cell.

Comment: Can you add a step to format the Excel sheet's first and third columns as TEXT  BEFORE pasting the data?

Comment: What action do you use to format the columns in power automate as its not in the Excel Actions?

Answer (score 0):

If you know which column may potentially have either number or alphanumeric type data, you can prepare a template Excel file in advance with text format (Excel: "Format Cells" => "Text") and have PAD to write the data on it.

Following is how it worked on my end when I wrote the data from PAD to the formatted Excel file.

[image]

[image]

[image]